# Choosing a specific drop-down choice that places a cursor in, or highlights, another cell for data entry

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, text-cursor, dropdownlist

In Excel, 2016, I have created a table that includes drop-down selections in some cells. [Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHQQk.png)

I would like to find a formula that prompts another cell to be highlighted, framed, or have a blinking cursor, to prompt the user to enter data into that cell IF the user chooses a particular drop-down choice.

For example, if the user chooses "Other" or "Multiple", they are automatically made aware of another cell where they are meant to add a description about "other" or "multiple".  In my image, "Multiple" is chosen from the drop-down list (column C, row 509) and the cursor would end up blinking in the column labeled "EXP" (column I, row 509).

I have tried a variety of IF statements but my drop-downs either change to reflect math commands, or I get a circular argument error. (Sorry, I wasn't noting the formulas I was working with to be able to reference them).

Comment: I suspect I may need to make a macro.  I have never done so, but would love suggestions to help me achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repositioning the cursor must be done via macros as far as I know.
You can work with conditional formats -- for example marking dependent cells with a red fill:

1. Select the list columns which you want to be filled when a certain
   value is selected in the DropDown.
2. In the home tab select "Conditional Formatting" in the "Styles"
   section and click "New Rule".
3. Select "Use a formula[...]" and enter a formula like
   `=AND($A2="Selection";ISBLANK(B2))`.
4. Select a Format (a fill color) via the "Format..." button.
5. Confirm with "OK".
6. Repeat steps 1 to 5 for each value from the DropDown you need highlighting for.

To adapt the formula following these rules:

1. `$A2` is the first cell in your DropDown-column. Make sure to keep the `$`.
2. `B2` (without any `$`) is the top left cell of the columns you selected in step 1.
3. `"Selection"` is the exact text string that you want to match from the DropDown.
4. If the cells you select in step one are the same for multiple DropDown selections, then the formula can look like this: `=AND(OR($A2="Selection1";$A2="Selection2";$A2="...",$A2="SelectionN");ISBLANK(B2))`

See this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgKnj.png).

I assumed that you want that behavior for the complete list columns!

Comment: With a bit of work and experimentation, I was able to implement your suggestions!  Thank you for your help!